# Npm Angular Cli Installation

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Can anyone help me? I have a hard time to install angular cli using npm.

First, I tried to install the file using **"npm install -g @angular/cli"**

After that an error came out:

[image]

Then, I set the proxy using **npm set 80 433** this is the port.
Then, **npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080**, and **npm config set https-proxy http://example.com:8080**

After setting the npm config I run again the **npm install -g @angular/cli** and still have the problem.

Here is the new error:

[image]

Now I don't know what to do next.

Can anyone help me please. I'm stuck! Thanks.

Comment: the error message said it's npm itself other than angular cli

Comment: Just for good measure can you try `npm cache clean`?  Seems unlikely that would be the cause.  Also, I assume `example.com` is just a placeholder for your corporate proxy?